# Why is my ExtJS singleton not working?

Tags: extjs, singleton, extjs4.2

I have an ExtJS singleton class.

As a test I am calling a method of it in app.js launch() function.

But the singleton static method is not defined.

I thought when I require the class the singleton becomes active?

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths: {
        'AM': 'app'
    }
});


Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    autoCreateViewport: true,


    requires: [
        'AM.localization.ResourceManager'
    ],


    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],


    launch: function() {
        alert(ResourceManager.initBundleLoader());
    }
});




Ext.define('AM.localization.ResourceManager', {
    alternateClassName: 'ResourceManager',
    singleton: true,

    init: function() {
        this.initBundleLoader();
    },

    statics: {
        test: 'here',
        initBundleLoader: function() {
            debugger;
            Ext.applyIf(Ext.Loader, {
                resourceBundles: new Object()
            });
        },

        registerBundle: function(bundleName, locale) {
            debugger;
            if(!Ext.Loader.hasOwnProperty('resourceBundles')) {
                this.initBundleLoader();
            }
            if(!Ext.Loader.resourceBundles.hasOwnProperty(bundleName)) {
                if(Ext.ClassManager.isCreated('AM.locale.' + locale + '.resources.' + bundleName)) {
                    this.resourceBundles.bundleName = Ext.create('AM.locale.' + locale + '.resources.' + bundleName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ext JS you can define class as `singleton` or define normal class with `statics` methods. You can not define statics methods in singleton.

If you define class as `singleton` Ext JS class post-processor immediately creates an instance of that class, and in your case store the reference in `AM.localization.ResourceManager`. Then you can access singleton methods like `AM.localization.ResourceManager.initBundleLoader()`

Good explenation of difference between normal class with statics methods and singleton you can find in third post here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?128646-Singleton-vs-class-with-all-static-members

So your class definition should be:

```
Ext.define('AM.localization.ResourceManager', {
    alternateClassName: 'ResourceManager',
    singleton: true,

    init: function() {
        this.initBundleLoader();
    },

    test: 'here',
    initBundleLoader: function() {
        debugger;
        Ext.applyIf(Ext.Loader, {
            resourceBundles: new Object()
        });
    },

    registerBundle: function(bundleName, locale) {
        debugger;
        if(!Ext.Loader.hasOwnProperty('resourceBundles')) {
            this.initBundleLoader();
        }
        if(!Ext.Loader.resourceBundles.hasOwnProperty(bundleName)) {
            if(Ext.ClassManager.isCreated('AM.locale.' + locale + '.resources.' + bundleName)) {
                this.resourceBundles.bundleName = Ext.create('AM.locale.' + locale + '.resources.' + bundleName);
            }
        }
    }
});
```